# Help with spearmint plant. Potential stem rot?

Tags: fungus, mint

I bought a mint plant a few months ago as my first plant and have been haphazardly taking care of it as best as I can. Apparently I had not been watering it enough as I read around in various forums and also plan on giving it more light. The stem and some of the leaves are very brown and I fear it might have some form of stem rot or other fungus that will end up being the death of it.

I have a few images of it here in an imgur album https://i.stack.imgur.com/4KO3E.jpg

What do you all think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar thing happen to my mint plant. I found that the following worked

- I took some cuttings and put the bottom in water until roots grew then planted them in the pot evenly spaced
- Cut back any rotten/dying leaves and stems. Mint plants are quite resilient and should grow back. In the past I have had to cut mine all the way back to just a single leaf and tint bit of stem and it recovered quite well with plenty of sunlight and water.